# FullCalendar v4 - time display options

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I have different eventTimeFormats displaying in different views, e..

```
{hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit'}
```

in timeGridDay view, but I don't want any eventTimeFormat to show in dayGridMonth view. Is this possible?

Comment: You mean you don't want the time of the event to show at all in the month view?

Comment: Correct. If I don't add the eventTimeFormat in the dayGridMonth view settings, fullcalendar puts the hour (and morning/afternoon) in to each event automatically. I have played around with different settings like {hour: " "} but just get an error.

Comment: Why not just use [displayEventTime](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/displayEventTime) in the dayGridMonth settings to disable the time?

Comment: Ah yes of course, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can use use [displayEventTime](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/displayEventTime) to disable the time:

```
displayEventTime: false
```

This can be applied to every view, or to specific views via that view's options.